# Trouble restoring mysql database from a backup

Tags: mysql

Friends, I have kept on tying and trying to restore a mysql database from a backup I created with mysqldump. I have been using this code (run in a command prompt Win XP and Win 7)

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\mysql --user=root --password=password --host= localhost --port= 3306 --database=dbname < C:/Backup/dbname.sql"
```

I get "The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect" error messsage. I have googled for this error to no avail as to do with mysql.

*My mysql server is up and running with no problem. (Even the mysqldump command works)
*Problem is the same even if I open the command prompt from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\mysql
*I have tried to remove "", did not help.
*I have tried to use back slashes () instead of (/), did not help.

For this one, I will really appreciate any help. What is the problem here? what is this filename,directory name.... syntax error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have quoted the whole command when you only need to quote the program name because there is a space in the path

Also the path for the backup file looks like it has "/" in place of "\"

Should be more like (assuming the options are correct:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\mysql.exe"  --user=root --password=password --host= localhost --port=3306 --database=dbname < C:\Backup\dbname.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quit the file you're trying to execute from the command line and instead log in in MySQL and once inside do:

```
source C:/Backup/dbname.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Open **Command Prompt** and type this

> **cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin**

Press Enter

or,

Directly open this directory "***C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin***" and Press **LEFT SHIFT KEY** from **keyboard** and **RIGHT CLICK** on the Directory Window.

2. **Type this**

   > **mysql -u root -p12345 -h localhost ""DATABASE_NAME"" < e:\tmp.sql**

It will work 100% correctly